Summation of any random variable and a gaussian random variable has a density function
I would like confirm if the below fact is true ask for a reference if it is true:
Let $X$ be a random variable, which does not necessarily have a density function. Let $G_{\sigma}$ be a gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $g_{\sigma}$ denotes its density function. Then $X_{\sigma}=X+G_{\sigma}$ has its density function $f_{\sigma}$ written as:
$f_{\sigma}=\int g_{\sigma}(x-y)\mu^X(dy)$
where $\mu^X$ is the law of $X$.
A follow-up question: if the above fact is true, does it hold for multivariate random variable?

It is true, but only for independent random variables. For example, it obviously doesn't work for $X = -G_{\sigma}$. 
A more general formula holds for independent variables $X$ and $Y$, let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ then
$$
P_{X+Y}(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} P_{X}(A-y)P_Y(dy).
$$
The exact form of distributions doesn't play a role here.
It also holds for independent multivariate random variables and random elements in general.
